# Удаление ордеров в MT5 на Python

Tags: python

Не могу уже неделю найти решение, прошу помощи.
Вопрос следубщий: как удалять/отменять лимитные/отложенные ордера на платформе MetaTrader5?
кто сталкивался? Помогите пожалуйста.

Я перепробовал несколько методов, которые нашёл:

```
close_request={
        "action": mt5.TRADE_ACTION_REMOVE,
        "symbol": "XAUUSD",
        "volume": lot,
        "type": mt5.ORDER_TYPE_SELL_LIMIT,
        "position": ticket,
        "price": price,
        "deviation": 1,
        "comment": "python script close",
        "type_time": mt5.ORDER_TIME_GTC, 
        "type_filling": mt5.ORDER_FILLING_IOC,
    }

    # send a close requesе
result=mt5.order_send(close_request)
```

В данном случае ошибка 10013 прилетает - не верный запрос. Но я уже всё перепробовал всё равно одно и то же получается.

И так же пробовал через команду:

`mt5.Close(symbol="XAUUSD", ticket=ticket)`

В документации вообще ни чего не сказанно на этот счёт. Отсюда и проблемы.
Кто сталкивался, подскажите пожалуйста.